# Sum of arrays of different dimension in R

Tags: r, arrays, sum, product

I have this code:

```
k = 20
rho = 0.5
pi_greco = array(rep(1/k, k), c(1,20,50))

pi_greco_x <- function(k, rho, pi_greco){
  E = array(diag(k),c(20, 20, 50))
  E[k,k,] = 0
  prob = (1-rho)*pi_greco + rho*E
  return(prob)
}
```

and in prob I need to sum each matrix of dimension 1x20 of pi_greco (multiplied by 1-rho) with each matrix of dimension 20x20 of E (multiplied by rho) in order to get 50 different matrix in prob. But how can I do it?

It is like saying that I would like to do

```
prob = (1-rho)*pi_greco[,,1] + rho*E[,,1]
```

But for all the 50 times without using a for cycle

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pi_greco has 1 row, E has 20 rows. Do you want to add pi_greco to each row of E?

Comment: yes, that's correct !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```r
k = 3
rho = 0.5
pi_greco = array(rep(1/k, k), c(1,20,50))

pi_greco_x <- function(k, rho, pi_greco){
  E = array(diag(k),c(k, 20, 50))
  E[k,k,] = 0

  p_rows <- Reduce(
      f=function(a,b){ abind( a, (1-rho)*pi_greco, along=1 ) },
      x=1:k,
      init=NULL
  )

  prob <- p_rows + rho*E
  return(prob)
}

pi_greco_x( k, rho, pi_greco )
```

I repeat the 1x20x50 to be 20x20x50 by using abind 20 times

This means they can now safely be added together. Working with more than two dimensions can be problematic. The typical human brain isn't very used to it.